# excel vba - syntax error

Tags: vba, excel

I can't quite figure out what the syntax error in Excel VBA is, the error I am seeing is: "run-time error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error"

```
Sheets("Totals").Select
x = Range("A139").Activate
Range("E139:AB166").Formula = "=INDEX(""Model""!$A$3:$Z$1000,MATCH($" & x & ",""Model""!$A$3:$A$1000,0),MATCH(E$3,""Model""!$A$3:$Z$3,0))"
```

I am attempting to use an Index Match Match formula where the index reference is another worksheet in the file. I am trying to populate the formula in Range E139:AB166, such that the x variable is locked to Column A and the last match function is locked on the third row (E$3).

```
x = Range("A139").Activate
```

This line of code should force the cursor to that cell in the 'model' worksheet. 'Model' is the name of the worksheet in the file. I thought "" were necessary to alert vba that the string refers to the worksheet name.
What if the worksheet name is comprised of two strings so "Model 1". What would be then the syntax, this?

```
""Model 1""!A3
```

'x' is the cell where new data is added, I wrote a line of code to have it dynamically changed.

```
x = Range("A" & insert_at).Activate
```

Where insert_at is a variable that equals the last row,in the worksheet that is not empty, + 1.

```
insert_at = lastRow + 1
```

So the idea is to dynamically add additional data from the 'Model' worksheet to the current worksheet 'Totals' below any existing data in the 'Totals worksheet.

I appreciate any assistance with this.

Thanks!

Comment: The double quotes. Where you need to show a quote as text use Chr(34) instead. Like `Chr(34) & "Model" & Chr(34)` instead of `""Model""`

Comment: @OAK is `x` suppose to be a different row number in Column A ?

Comment: Alternatively to @Moacir's suggestion, you can double up on the quotes to use them as a literal `"` character. For example, `"""Model"""` - the outer quotes are the string delimiters, and the `""` preceding and following the word `Model` represents a literal `"`.

Comment: What means the second line ??? `x = Range("A139").Activate`

Comment: Since `Model` is a sheet name (I hope so) it doesn't need the `""` , just the `!` at the end, so your formula shousd be : `"=INDEX(Model!$A$3:$Z$1000,MATCH($" & x & ",Model!$A$3:$A$1000,0),MATCH(E$3,Model!$A$3:$Z$3,0))"` . If you could just tell us what does `x` suppose to be ???

Comment: what is X ? is it the value in Range("A139") ? is it the Address of the cell ? or you suppose to `Select` it? if yes, why ? you realy don't need to

Comment: @ShaiRado thanks for the information. I tried to revise my initial post and add more information.

Answer (score 0):

Type a correct working formula in E139 then use [this little Sub](http://idevlop.blogspot.lu/2009/09/generer-du-vba-avec-excel-vba.html) I wrote once, to turn it into a vba usable formula string.

```
 Sub RngToVba(src As Range)  
 'writes the VBA code to re-create the formulae in given range  
 'by Patrick Honorez - www.idevlop.com  
 'usage: from debug window, type RngToVba [L14:R14]  
 ' or RngToVba range("L14:R14")  
  Dim c As Range  
  For Each c In src  
  Debug.Print "range(""" & c.Address & """).formula = """ & _  
        Replace(c.Formula, """", """""") & """"""  
  Next c  
 End Sub
```

And...for god's sake, stop using those useless `select` and `activate`.

```
Sheets("Totals").Range("E139:AB166").Formula = someString
```

is faster, easier to debug, and more readable.